# Wrap an existing Blazor Web Assembly app into a .NET MAUI Hybrid App

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, maui, maui-blazor, blazor-hybrid

I watched this tutorial on how to create a .NET MAUI Blazor App

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnoCU5XGBh4

However I have an existing Blazor Web Assembly app, what is the best recommended way to wrap it into a BlazorWebView? I have dug around for tutorials but as its fairly new there is not much content.

Comment: Are you looking to migrate from blazor to .NET MAUI blazor hybrid? or you want to resue/share the pages, components and other static files between blazor and .NET MAUI blazor hybrid?

Comment: @fingers10 I'm looking to write a blazor web assembly app than reuse it as a android app

Comment: you can create a web assembly app and move the pages to common razor class library and reuse the same in MAUI and Blazor. Checkout the sample repo https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorHybrid

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create a web assembly app
2. Move the pages/components to common razor class library
3. Create MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project
4. Reuse the common razor class library in MAUI and Blazor.

Checkout the sample [repo](https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorHybrid)

Comment: What do you do with the authentication that is happening in the blazor app? Does that need to change?

Comment: No need. Authentication will automatically redirect to your Identity Provider.

Comment: Worth noting that Web project in referenced repo is to demonstrate alternative deployment to MAUI. If you simply want Blazor in MAUI you only need Common (Razor library) and MAUI as a startup project.

Comment: Great repo, has helped me a lot, but I've been hunting all day to get an Authentication principle to pass successfully to something like <AuthorizeView> on the front pages

Comment: I'm planning to make a production app using MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project. Will post here if I'm able to solve Authentication issue.

Comment: I have the following repo with a solution containing Blazer Server, Blazer Webassembly and Maui Blazor with a shared Razor component library with bare minimum setup to quickly get started: https://github.com/iceHub82/Blazor.Shared