# .NET 8 Blazor Web App, MAUI Blazor App & PWA (Sharing UI)

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am working on a Blazor Web App (.NET 8) and am trying to get it to work with sharing its UI with a .NET MAUI Blazor App.

Has anyone else managed to get this working yet?

Also is it possible to have it setup to work as a PWA as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to MAUI Blazor App. See fingers10's solution in this case: [Wrap an existing Blazor Web Assembly app into a .NET MAUI Hybrid App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74043694/wrap-an-existing-blazor-web-assembly-app-into-a-net-maui-hybrid-app):

1. Create a web assembly app
2. Move the pages/components to common razor class library
3. Create MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project
4. Reuse the common razor class library in MAUI and Blazor.

You can also check this:[How to run MAUI Blazor App in a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72323525/how-to-run-maui-blazor-app-in-a-web-browser) Hope these can help you.