# Blazor Server AspNetCore.Identity components share with MAUI Blazor Hybrid

Tags: blazor-server-side, maui-blazor

I have a minimal login/registration/confirmation app backed by AspNetCore.Identity and I tried to share the identity page components with MAUI Blazor Hybrid app but it failed with an error NETSDK1082 There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available.

So for each Blazor server identity page i have a component in a RCL.
Pages/Login.razor -> ComponentLib/Login.razor

When I tried to reference the component from the RCL in a page in MAUI app it failed.

Is it even possible to share the components that use the AspNetCore.Identity with non Web apps?

I use SignInManager, UserManager and the likes.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to fingers10's solution in this case: [Wrap an existing Blazor Web Assembly app into a .NET MAUI Hybrid App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74043694/wrap-an-existing-blazor-web-assembly-app-into-a-net-maui-hybrid-app) ?

1. Create a web assembly app
2. Move the pages/components to common razor class library
3. Create MAUI Blazor Hybrid Project
4. Reuse the common razor class library in MAUI and Blazor.

You can also check this:[How to run MAUI Blazor App in a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72323525/how-to-run-maui-blazor-app-in-a-web-browser).  In addition, as far as I know, you can share web UI Razor components, code, and static assets between web and native client apps built using Blazor. See this doc: [Share assets across web and native clients using a Razor class library (RCL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Comment: Sorry, I specified that I'm using Blazor Server.