# .NET MAUI - Can I use Authentication WebAPI from existing Blazor project?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, maui

We already have a running Blazor WebAssembly App (ASP.NET Core hosted) and implemented Authentication/Authorization according to [this tutorial](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/authentication-in-blazor-webassembly/). We added Roles to the project in order to restrict users to certain content.
The backend is using *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity* as NuGet dependency.
We want to implement a .NET MAUI App for this project, which should use the same database for the users, so no one has to register again.
We still want to use the same backend for our Blazor application, therefore the solution must be compatible with both Blazor and .NET MAUI. 
Is there a way for .NET MAUI to use the same Users/Roles which were created with *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity*? If possible, how do we render UI elements based on the role of the user?

Comment: Since you already have a Blazor WebAssembly App, you can try to wrap it into a .NET MAUI, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74043694/wrap-an-existing-blazor-web-assembly-app-into-a-net-maui-hybrid-app

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks for your reply. But I think that this would not be the optimal solution, as our MAUI and Blazor application really differ in functionality and should only share authentication.

Comment: Also, I notice that the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity) is decerped, you may find an alternative way to get it done.

Comment: I'm not sure which is the latest nuget, but Microsoft.AspCore.Identity is current https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity. With Identity you have many different types of identity.  You chose the original Forms Based Authentication.  Approach the same way as WebAssembly, register Identity in MauiProgram.cs  and handle authentication.  Make sure your ApplicationDBContext uses the same connection string and it should work.